# How to get the current Linux theme with Python?

Tags: python, themes, gtk3, xfce

I need to get the current Icon Theme in the system. The problem is that there are a lot of environments as GNOME, XFCE, MATE...

Please, how could I **get the current Icon Theme**? I'm thinking that it'll be with `Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()`, but I didn't get a good result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean [gtk.icon_theme_get_default()](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkicontheme.html#function-gtk--icon-theme-get-default) ?

Comment: @PM2Ring: I need GTK3 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no universal solution for all systems.

You will need to use different approaches depending on the environment, and then most likely include a switch depending on the present environment. It will take some research...
In modern gtk3 environments you can query and change basically any setting quite conveniently via `gsettings`.
For example, in GNOME:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme
```

will return the current icon-theme.
In **Cinnamon**, you can query similarly with:

```
gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.interface icon-theme
```

in **Mate**, the key `icon-theme` would be defined in schema `org.mate.interface`, and under **Xfce** the available tool is **xfconf-query**:

```
xfconf-query -lvc xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName
```

With window managers you can read the appropriate config files like for example `gtk-icon-theme-name=` from **$HOME/.gtkrc-2.0**,
or it might even be defined in **~/.Xresources**, or (rather outdated) in **$HOME/gtk-3.0/settings.ini**, possibly also in **$HOME/.config/qt5ct/qt5ct.conf** ;) ... and so on :)